# Adobe Illustrator Tool selectors not working

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I just got the Adobe Master Collection CS5.5.  Long time Photoshop user but just playing around with Illustrator for the first time.  I am already having an issue though.  See photo...

[image]

When I try to right or left click on any of the arrows on the tool buttons to expand them it does not do anything.  For example the rectangle tool will not let me change it to a circle tool or even view that the circle tool is an option.  Same with all the buttons, any ideas?

Using Windows 7 12gb ram i7processor and SSD drives

Also I have tried re-starting the program

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand the toolbar buttons to show hidden tools in Illustrator, you click *and hold* the mouse button down.

More CS5 toolbar info from help.adobe.com [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6335a.html).

Answer (score 0):

I look thru Adobe forum and found an answer.
By pressing ALT and clicking on tool it's available to choose another tool.

https://forums.adobe.com/message/7121543#7121543